# Paint Eleven Squares

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

I was inspired by this great question: [Paint Eight Squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110235/paint-eight-squares)

Given a $5 \times 5$ grid of white squares, can you paint **11** of the squares black so that each white square is orthogonally adjacent to exactly **two** black squares?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is

> yes

and here's why:

> [image: 5x5 grid with some cells colored black]

Comment: That is correct! In fact this is the only solution I found and it is pretty.

Comment: Pfft. That's cheating. "can you paint 11 of the squares black so that each white square is orthogonally adjacent to exactly two black squares?" yes, trivially, if none of the squares are white! `:-)`

Comment: they are white to Deusovi...