# 6x6 Minesweeper grid with all threes

Tags: combinatorics, minesweeper

Can you place 16 mines on a 6x6 Minesweeper grid such that each number produced is a 3? **Bonus:** can you find multiple solutions that are not rotations or reflections of each other? Good luck!

Related question: [Paint Eleven Squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110250/paint-eleven-squares)

Comment: Note that 16 is the minimum possible.

Comment: Any proof for that? (that 16 is the minimum possible)

Comment: I don't have a proof, but I have an efficient program that finds these grids. From many attempts it always finds 16.

Comment: I can confirm that 16 is the minimum number of mines to make every non-mine cell have value 3.

Comment: Interesting.  Another question would be if there is a pattern that will infinitely tile a plane in this manner.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis "every non-mine cell have value 3" is not equivalent to "each number produced is a 3". The question leaves the possibility of open (non-mine, non-number) cells, but your comment does not. Unless it is provably impossible to have open cells in such a scenario?

Comment: @Flater Such cells are equivalent to having value zero (no neighbouring mines), and I just checked and it makes no difference. Apart from the completely empty board, 16 mines is also the minimum where every non-mine cell has exactly 0 or 3 neighbouring mines.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Fair enough that it counts as number zero.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this arrangement of mines will work (red squares are mines)

> [image]

Comment: That is correct! Can you find another, completely different, solution?

Answer (score 9):

Apart from the solution that hexomino found, there is another solution:

> [image]

According to my computer program, there are no other solutions up to symmetry (so 4 solutions if we count the rotated/reflected pattern as distinct).

Comment: yep that's the other solution. Interestingly my program mostly finds this one and very rarely the other one. It must a strong local minima.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky My program does an exhaustive search. The 7x7 board, 25 mines, all empty cells value 4 is an interesting case with a unique solution.

Comment: Cool, I will see if I can find it.

Comment: I found the 25 mine case for 7x7. Very nice and symmetric. Feel free top post it as another puzzle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Oh of course!

Answer (score 8):

This is equivalent to asking how to place kings on a 6x6 board so that each empty square is attacked by 3 of those kings. This is a special case of the problem posed [here](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1111.html). That web site gives hexomino's 16-king [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/110263) for the 6x6, among

> 3, 5, 8, 12, 16, 29 (sic), 27

-king solutions for the 2x2, ..., 8x8 boards.

Answer (score 7):

After seeing hexomino's solution and your comment, I started playing with (manually generated, but automatically checked) ideas in Excel, with the goal of

> "I wonder if there's a solution with a corner clear?"

and quickly found

> [image: first answer with corners clear]

I also found/verified the other known solution...

> [image: duplicate of @hexomino solution]

But other avenues explored have

> so far led to dead-ends / contradictions - cells that need more adjacent mines next to clusters of other cells that can't have any more mines next to them etc. or getting edited into something approaching a duplicate of the other known answers...

which would be fairly obvious to @jaap-scherphuis, who I now see posted while I was typing up mine...

I also noticed that

> The two solutions are identical in the central 4x4 box, implying this part of the solution is unique.

Comment: I wonder what forces the centre to be unique?